# Battleship: How to automate instances creation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I'm making a game of battleships. I created a Ship class to give the ships a location.

After making the class, I had to create all the instances, and I was wondering if there is a way to automate that.

Most of the program is irrelevant, but I'm leaving it in just in case it might affect whether or not it can be automated.

```
import random

class Ship(object):

    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length

    def direction(self):
        vh = random.choice(['v','h'])
        return vh

    def location(self):
        space = []
        row = random.randint(0, 10-self.length)
        column = random.randint(0, 10-self.length)
        if self.direction == 'v':
            for x in range(self.length):
                space.append(f'{column}{row+x}')
        else:
            for x in range(self.length):
                space.append(f'{column}{row+x}')
        return space

ships_amount = {
    'carrier' : 1,
    'battleship' : 2,
    'cruiser' : 3,
    'destroyer' : 4
}

ships_length = {
    'carrier' : 5,
    'battleship' : 4,
    'cruiser' : 3,
    'destroyer' : 2
}
```

I want to do this:

```
carrier1 = Ship(ships_length['carrier'])
battleship1 = Ship(ships_length['battleship'])
battleship2 = Ship(ships_length['battleship'])
cruiser1 = Ship(ships_length['cruiser'])
cruiser2 = Ship(ships_length['cruiser'])
cruiser3 = Ship(ships_length['cruiser'])
destroyer1 = Ship(ships_length['destroyer'])
destroyer2 = Ship(ships_length['destroyer'])
destroyer3 = Ship(ships_length['destroyer'])
destroyer4 = Ship(ships_length['destroyer'])
```

but automated

Comment: What do you want to end up with? Would a list do? You currently get named variables for each ship.

Comment: Do you want to iterate over `ships_length`?

Comment: I have tried iterating over ships_amount and iterating over the amount value for each key, then creating an instance for each ship, but it doesnt work

Comment: @doctorlove I don't understand what you mean by what I want to end up with. I just want to create the instances. I can get the locations later on for other stuff.

Comment: Is there any reason to create individual names for each object? There are several ways to do so, but it is not very useful if you want to access them programatically, later on. Better create a dict and use the name as key, instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the ships you want and lookup their lengths to make them:

```
 ships = []
 for type_of_ship in ships_amount:
   ships.append(Ship(ships_length[type_of_ship]))
```

or even

```
ships = [Ship(ships_length[k]) for k in ships_amount]
```

(In the second example, `k`y is a shorthand for `key`, or what is now called `type_of_ship` in the for loop)

This will give you one of each type of ship.

This will not give you variables named 'carrier1' etc. but you will be able to do stuff with each item in the `ships`.

e.g.

```
for ship in ships:
    print(ship.length)
```

To get sthe stated number, or amount of each type of ships, you need to make extra ships in the loop.
By iterating over `items()` you get a key and value back, which I have called `k` and `v` though deserve better names.
The value in your dictionary tells you how many:

```
ships = []
for k, v in ships_amount.items():
    ships.extend([Ship(ships_length[k]) for _ in range(v)])
```

This gives you the 10 ships you asked for.

Comment: Maybe it would have been more helpful to use representative names, like 'ship_type' instead of 'k' in the first example. That way, it may be easier to understand what is returned when iterating over the dict. But anyway, a nice little summary!

Comment: Hacking in a hurry - no excuse though.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a child class of Ship for each Ship model you need, you can group them in a Fleet, then create the fleet directly in one line of code...

Maybe something like this:

```
import random

class Ship:             # this becomes an abstract class, not to be instanciated
                        # you could have it inherit from ABC (Abstract Base Class)
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = self.__class__.length
        self.heading = None
        self.set_heading()

        self.location = None
        self.set_location()

    def set_heading(self):
        self.heading = random.choice(['v','h'])

    def set_location(self):   # this method needs more work to prevent
                              # ships to occupy the same spot and overlap 
        space = []
        row = random.randint(0, 10 - self.length)
        column = random.randint(0, 10 - self.length)
        if self.heading == 'v':
            for c in range(self.length):
                space.append((row, column + c))
        elif self.heading == 'h':
            for r in range(self.length):
                space.append((row + r, column))
        self.location = space

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__} at {self.location}'


class AircraftCarrier(Ship):    # every type of ship inherits from the base class Ship
    length = 5                  # Each class of ship can have its own specifications
                                # here, length, but it could be firepower, number of sailors, cannons, etc...

class BattleShip(Ship):
    length = 4

class Cruiser(Ship):
    length = 3

class Destroyer(Ship):
    length = 2


class Fleet:
    ships_number = {AircraftCarrier : 1,
                    BattleShip: 2, 
                    Cruiser: 3, 
                    Destroyer: 4}
    def __init__(self):
        self.ships = [ship() for ship, number in Fleet.ships_number.items() 
                      for _ in range(number)]

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join([str(ship) for ship in self.ships])


if __name__ == '__main__':

    fleet = Fleet()         # <-- the creation of the entire Fleet of Ships 
    print(fleet)            #     takes now one line of code now
```

#### Example Output:

*(The locations are randomly assigned and will vary from run to run.)*

```
AircraftCarrier at [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2)]
BattleShip at [(5, 3), (6, 3), (7, 3), (8, 3)]
BattleShip at [(5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1)]
Cruiser at [(4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7)]
Cruiser at [(0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7)]
Cruiser at [(6, 6), (7, 6), (8, 6)]
Destroyer at [(4, 8), (5, 8)]
Destroyer at [(3, 5), (4, 5)]
Destroyer at [(1, 5), (1, 6)]
Destroyer at [(2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

#### Adding a new type of ship:

Adding a new type of ship is very easy: It suffices to create a new class inheriting from the abstract base class `Ship`, and adding the number of the new ships to the fleet composition:

```
class Submarine(Ship):
    length = 1

Fleet.ships_number[Submarine] = 5   # or add this entry directly in the class Fleet data
```

The fleet has now an additional 5 submarines:

```
AircraftCarrier at [(4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1)]
BattleShip at [(5, 5), (6, 5), (7, 5), (8, 5)]
BattleShip at [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)]
Cruiser at [(5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4)]
Cruiser at [(2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0)]
Cruiser at [(7, 7), (8, 7), (9, 7)]
Destroyer at [(4, 3), (5, 3)]
Destroyer at [(2, 1), (2, 2)]
Destroyer at [(0, 8), (1, 8)]
Destroyer at [(3, 6), (3, 7)]
Submarine at [(8, 8)]
Submarine at [(0, 7)]
Submarine at [(3, 4)]
Submarine at [(5, 9)]
Submarine at [(9, 3)]
```

Comment: Good proposal, but one flaw (apart from potential overlapping): NO carrier can be placed in the bottom 5 rows or right 5 columns at all, because length is blindly subtracted for both headings. 
"row = random.randint(0, 10 - self.length)" could be replaced by "row = random.randint(0, 10 - (self.length * (self.heading == 'v') or 1))" and 
"column = random.randint(0, 10 - self.length)" by "column = random.randint(0, 10 - (self.length * (self.heading == 'h') or 1))"
Length is only subtracted for rows if heading is 'v' and for cols if heading is 'h'. Otherwise 1 is subtracted for ship width.

Comment: "self.length = self.__class__.length" The class attribute 'length' would be sufficient, since the ship length is an immanent property of the ship type. Unless we expect divergent lengths for the same ship types.

Comment: Thank you. Yes Michael, you may be correct, I must say that I did not really check the full logic of the positioning method as it was somewhat outside the scope of the question. 
I don't understand your second comment (I voted on it by mistake, and I cannot undo it)

Comment: Reblochon, I fully understand and you already stated it needs to be revised. I know it was only part of the generously added value. My question was: why do you create an instance attribute "self.length" in the __init__ of each Ship, in addition to the class attribute "length" defined in the final classes? Isn't it sufficient to have the length defined as class attribute? You can access it in the abstract class using "self.length", just like it was an instance attribute.

Comment: Ah, ok, i understand the question now. You are formally correct @MichaelS, this would be sufficient. In any event, this is a good question, that, like most design choices does not have an absolute answer.

Comment: That said, attributing length as an attribute for each ship instance felt like the right thing to do at the time. For instance, I like each object to have its own length: class attributes affect all objects upon being modified at the class level; once created, a ship of a type will hardly change length, but you could have larger submarines, and do this by modifying the length? In addition, this length instance attribute might later be used to represent the remaining active length of a ship, after some of its segments have been hit...

Comment: To address the placement of the ships, I imagine it would be useful to have an `Ocean` object, or a `MaritimeMap` object where the ships would be located. This object could verify if the ship placement is adequate. It would also qualify the shots as hit or miss...

Comment: That's why I wrote "Unless we expect divergent lengths for the same ship types". In the classical game, the ship class was used as a synonym for the (start) length. You are right, one could (mis)use the length to represent the remaining segments, f.i. for easier calculation of the game status. I would do that more explicitly by using a dedicated instance attribute like "length_remaining" or "damage", or a similarly named function to count them. Actually, I only wanted to encourage to define new instance attributes only if needed for a purpose.